# In Highcharts, when I click the 'View Data' in the extended toolbar, the 'Category' in the generated table cannot be translated

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In `Highcharts`, when I `click` the `View Data` in the extended toolbar, the `Category` in the generated table cannot be translated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC2AM.png)

hope to translate this

hope to translate this

hope to translate this

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        viewFullscreen: '全画面表示',
        printChart: 'グラフを印刷',
        downloadJPEG: 'JPEG画像でダウンロード',
        downloadPDF: 'PDF文書でダウンロード',
        downloadPNG: 'PNG画像でダウンロード',
        downloadSVG: 'SVG形式でダウンロード',
        downloadCSV: 'CSV形式でダウンロード',
        downloadXLS: 'XLS形式でダウンロード',
        viewData: 'データテーブルを表示',
        hideData: 'データテーブルを非表示',
        noData: "データがありません"
    },
    noData: {
        style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            fontSize: '20px',
            color: '#303030'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This value is equal to the title of the x-axis, so you can use the `xAxis.title.text` property to set this text, and if you don't want it to be visible in the graph below the axis, you can set `xAxis.title.enabled` to `false`:

```
xAxis: {
  title: {
    text: 'カスタムテキスト',
    enabled: false // to hide on chart
  }
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t79k8yfp/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.title.text 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.title.enabled

Another way for other chart types that don't have axes, such as pie charts, is to use the `exporting.csv.columnHeaderFormatter()` function:

```
exporting: {
  csv: {
    columnHeaderFormatter: function(item, key) {
      if (!item || item instanceof Highcharts.Axis) {
        return 'カスタムテキスト'
      } else {
        return item.name;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lq20pgyh/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.csv.columnHeaderFormatter

Comment: but pie chart no xAxis. what should I do

Comment: Good point, I added to the answer another way for graph types that don't have axes.